# PHP page won't UPDATE on page RELOAD but will on page REFRESH

Tags: php, refresh, reload, meta, head

When I update my static PHP website and click another page from menu, then return to home page.  Nothing is updated.  Only if I press F5 it will actually refresh the cache and update the information.

I need my viewers to see these updates.  How can I stop it from cache? I added this (referenced from other qurstion answers):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

But it won't help either. Below is my header meta info.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- some meta tags, important for SEO"--> 
    <meta name="description" content="content description removed for security"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="content keywords removed for security" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</head>
```

Comment: there's no php here

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is from a PHP file. Because it has PHP code in it.  But as I stated above this is just my Meta Data, any help appreciated.

Comment: @halfer Did you really have to edit that out? Was it "in your way"? You could at least help me out by answering my question. God Bless

Comment: Hi Sammy, couple of things: (1) it's quite normal for [non-critical information to be edited out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495), and (2) some people just edit, some people just answer, and some people just ask. No-one is obligated to do anything. Hope that helps.